# Green to Red Gradient color in jquery in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I calculate data and Fetch from the database and showing in the table in percent format.

Here is my table

```
<table id="myTable" class="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr class="">
    <th>Types of Work</th>
    <th>value</th>
    <th>Count Percent(%)</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
    <th>Hours Percent(%)</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php $count=0; 
      $count_percent=0;
      $total_time=0;
?>
  <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row->t_name;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->NUM;?></td>
      <td><?php echo round($row->count_percent,1)."%";?></td>
      <td><?php echo round($row->value_sum,1);?></td>
      <td><?php echo round($row->duration_percent,1)."%";?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
        $count += $row->value_sum; 
        $total_time += $row->NUM;  
      } 
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><?php echo "$total_time";?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo round("$count",1); ?></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want Gradient color from Green to red in the table based on percent.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(".myTable .valueTD").each(function(){
    var r = Math.min(100,parseInt(this.innerHTML,10)*2+10);
    var g = Math.min(100,200-parseInt(this.innerHTML,10)*2+10);
    this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + g + "%," + r + "%,0%)"
});
```

I search on google but didn't find the answer.

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: is anyone is here please help me to find the answer

Comment: you could just make an associative array with several color options and choose one of the colors based on percentage, would that suffice?

Comment: @Andrew . I don't have much more knowledge in javascript please help me

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Do you want a progress bar?  Where/why do you apply this gradient?  Please revise your question in the form of (when 'x', I would like 'y'.  I have tried 'z')

Comment: @FissureKing I believe he is trying to get a shade between red and green based on a percentage

Comment: @FissureKing . I am trying to show background color in table cell based on percentage. if percentage high then it should show green. if the percentage decrease from high to low then the color decrease from green to red in gradient

Comment: @xr33dx Ok, and what have you tried so far?  By the way, I believe that when you say 'gradient', you mean 'hue'.  Gradient implies an active transition.

Comment: @FissureKing please see my edit jquery. it show green in 80% but I want to show green which is maximum(Ex: if there is three percent 40 30 and 20 percent, 40 will be green 30 will be middle of red and green and 20 is red)